# How to bring focus on to the new window, if the parent window has been already got closed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, automation

I am automating an application from our organisation and I've been struggling with this problem. When I started my Webdriver (Running IE mode on Edge) it opens a main window consists of a login page after giving the credentials (If credentials are correct) the page loads and then closes the main window, and after that a new window got opened. The problem here is how can I focus on to the new window if the focused parent window got closed already, I'd tried all my tricks but no use. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
//opened login page 
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
String childWindow = parentWindow;

//performed login page Authentication and main window page loading for 2-5 secs
while(parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(childWindow)) { 
  for(String w : driver.getWindowHandles()){
   if(!w.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindow)){
      childWindow = w;
      break;
    } 
   } 
} 

driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
```

Comment: Can you please add in the question what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Akzy thanks for the reply, I has updated the question with the code which I  had tried it got worked sometimes but sometimes it is failing, if the parent window closes first then this code is failing.

Comment: As far as I know, if you need to switch focus with IE driver, you usually use the switchTo() method you mentioned. But it doesn't work either, and it seems to be affected by page load speed. So I'm afraid I can't think of a better way. Maybe you can think of a way from a design perspective.

Comment: Yeah @XudongPeng Understood, but is there a way to prevent the parent window from getting closed before the child window gets popping? Not like in the selenium but any outside configuration for the IE browser?

Comment: Maybe you could try creating and using a listener that listens for the verify certificate action (click event), but I'm not sure if this will do what you want. And as far as I know, there is no such browser setting that suits your needs.